# How to "ctrl+z" in smart git?

Tags: git, github, smartgit

I accidentally deleted the fonts from my project and decided to roll back the project to the latest version, save the fonts and go back to the current one. But the problem is that the last commit was a long time ago, and before I went to it, I did not keep the current version of the project. Is there any way to just go back to the current version of the project, by canceling my last actions? Changes were made only localy...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite confusing, especially the title.

You can simply clone your local repository to another local directory. That will give you the HEAD commit, assuming you are on `master`. If not, just checkout the relevant branch.

From that clone, you can manually copy your deleted files back to the original repository.